# Solved Mathing Last str + 1 return 50

Tags: c#

Hello iam trying to math this to get result = 2

```
string str = "1005480701";
Console.WriteLine(str.Last() + 1);
```

it should be 2 but the result is 50 
can someone explain why that happen please

Comment: `str.Last()` returns the last _character_ of the string, which is `'1'`, not the integer `1`. Try `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(str.Last()) + 1);`

Comment: @RenéVogt `Convert.ToInt32(str.Last())` will also give you 49.  You have to change the `char` to a `string` first `Convert.ToInt32(str.Last().ToString())` or alternatively `str.Last() - '0'` would also work.

Comment: thanks all for helping

Comment: @juharr thanks, didn't know that. I normally use int.Parse and only wrote Convert.ToInt32 here because I felt that's more common on SO.. well obviously not for chars.

Answer (score 5):

`string.Last()` returns the `char` `'1'`. The UTF-16 code for `'1'` is `49` and if you add `1` to `49`, you get `50`.

You have to transform the character to the number it represents, for example with `int.Parse()`.

```
...
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(str.Last().ToString()) + 1);
...
```